# How to calculate data between 15 minutes range in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of timebands and values together:

```
2013-03-04 02:00:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:01:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:02:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:03:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:04:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:05:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:06:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:07:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:08:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:09:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:10:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:11:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:12:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:13:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:14:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:15:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:16:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:17:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:18:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:19:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:20:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:21:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:22:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:23:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:24:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:25:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:26:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:27:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:28:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:29:00 UTC
2013-03-04 02:30:00 UTC
```

Each of timebands has it's own float number value. Just like:

```
1.192069669
1.398097386
1.51857279
1.667887277
1.919998368
2.007405113
2.079283295
2.160574819
2.184922836
2.194639015
2.234917032
2.278915283
2.307196654
2.265553703
2.209039541
2.204034995
2.271997186
2.192411672
2.268617205
2.136996194
2.20568788
2.202653527
2.186529626
2.206325387
2.182503664
1.196174184
1.206075579
1.226468123
1.177213548
1.060684314
1.215226185
1.268223732
1.334227719
1.503234406
1.699964124
1.680645046
1.767723116
1.733957416
1.79358097
1.847852493
1.918378765
1.95619668
1.900485186
1.908825891
2.138246816
2.170221961
2.131884782
2.140921904
2.171028766
2.392254099
2.497088696
```

## Question is:

I need to sum up each 15 minutes values and take their arithmetic avarage.

For example data between 02:00 and 02:14 is first group
02:15 and 02:29 is second group. 02:30 and 02:44 .....

I need avareges of each group.

It must be done with either with `for` or `while` using 15.minutes time helper but I couldn't make it work.

How to handle these?

Thank you.

### Edit:

Array structure is like this:

```
ras_date                   tv1_rating              tv2_rating             tv3_rating
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-03-04 02:00:00 UTC   |  2.184922836     |   2.278915283     |     2.278915283
2013-03-04 02:01:00 UTC   |  2.194639015     |   3.278915283     |     1.278915283
2013-03-04 02:02:00 UTC   |  0.234917032     |   4.278915283     |     0.278915283
2013-03-04 02:03:00 UTC   |  2.278915283     |   1.278915283     |     2.278915283
..
.
```

I want to calculate each TV stations rating avarage for 15 minutes according to ras_date.

And well, using for and while was just a guess of mine. Any kind of solution is welcomed. Thank you.

### Edit-2:

```
[#<DataFile id: 48009, timeband: \"02:00\", ras_date: \"2013-03-04 02:00:00\", created_at: \"2013-03-05 18:45:16\", updated_at: \"2013-03-05 18:45:16\", tv1_rtg: 0.231275974, tv1_shr: 3.459938790606675, tv2_rtg: 0.465407082, tv2_shr: 6.9625910058208715, tv4_rtg: 0.024855499, tv4_shr: 0.3718436621954748, tv5_rtg: 0.355105523, tv5_shr: 5.3124557321564705, tv3_rtg: 0.306065103, tv3_shr: 4.578800400255703, tv6_rtg: 0.425388078, tv6_shr: 6.363898016202141, tv8_rtg: 0.184050299, tv8_shr: 2.7534324379620037, tv7_rtg: 0.13351472, tv7_shr: 1.9974092027604597, tv8_rtg: 0.104982397, tv8_shr: 1.5705594551346256, ttv_rtg: 6.684394956, ttv_shr: 100.0, tv9_shr: 3.8946589139877266, tv9_rtg: 0.260334384>, #<DataFile id: 48010, timeband: \"02:01\", ras_date: \"2013-03-04 02:01:00\", created_at: \"2013-03-05 18:45:16\", updated_at: \"2013-03-05 18:45:16\", tv1_rtg: 0.111862045, tv1_shr: 1.6818552137556582, tv2_rtg: 0.464504362, tv2_shr: 6.983861979654901, tv4_rtg: 0.057792275, tv4_shr: 0.8689116940741676, tv5_rtg: 0.353541524, tv5_shr: 5.315526418442655, tv3_rtg: 0.315364133, tv3_shr: 4.741526147833099, tv6_rtg: 0.463173951, tv6_shr: 6.963859138863031, tv8_rtg: 0.188181065, tv8_shr: 2.8293180703101073, tv7_rtg: 0.148338388, tv7_shr: 2.2302800852416897, tv8_rtg: 0.112267205, tv8_shr: 1.6879468282832242, ttv_rtg: 6.651110279, ttv_shr: 100.0, tv9_shr: 3.673313247735431, tv9_rtg: 0.244316115>, #<DataFile id: 48011, timeband: \"02:02\", ras_date: \"2013-03-04 02:02:00\", created_at: \"2013-03-05 18:45:16\", updated_at: \"2013-03-05 18:45:16\", tv1_rtg: 0.096118706, tv1_shr: 1.4904838004557073, tv2_rtg: 0.482073193, tv2_shr: 7.475363690398179, tv4_rtg: 0.045212074, tv4_shr: 0.7010900030427445, tv5_rtg: 0.367055659, tv5_shr: 5.691821460903709, tv3_rtg: 0.336406586, tv3_shr: 5.2165555245782205, tv6_rtg: 0.463173951, tv6_shr: 7.18229884158621, tv8_rtg: 0.175622569, tv8_shr: 2.72332623879596, tv7_rtg: 0.13351472, tv7_shr: 2.0703725171079563, tv8_rtg: 0.109862708, tv8_shr: 1.7036078965544506, ttv_rtg: 6.448825943, ttv_shr: 100.0, tv9_shr: 4.214133803611018, tv9_rtg: 0.271762154>, #<DataFile id: 48012, timeband: \"02:03\", ras_date: \"2013-03-04 02:03:00\", created_at: \"2013-03-05 18:45:16\", updated_at: \"2013-03-05 18:45:16\", tv1_rtg: 0.111568925, tv1_shr: 1.7336392363465083, tv2_rtg: 0.589141334, tv2_shr: 9.154507246313642, tv4_rtg: 0.100518614, tv4_shr: 1.5619314537051374, tv5_rtg: 0.402849844, tv5_shr: 6.259774358446762, tv3_rtg: 0.328333577, tv3_shr: 5.101886315541693, tv6_rtg: 0.43495935, tv6_shr: 6.758715254949115, tv8_rtg: 0.175622569, tv8_shr: 2.7289514208940524, tv7_rtg: 0.13351472, tv7_shr: 2.0746489869093736, tv8_rtg: 0.102741203, tv8_shr: 1.5964676607777801, ttv_rtg: 6.435532991, ttv_shr: 100.0, tv9_shr: 1.7713521655381412, tv9_rtg: 0.113995953>]
```

### Edit-3:

My array file is like above (see edit-2).

when I try:

```
d = DataFile.all
d.each_slice(15) { |v| puts v.inject(0.0) { |sum, el| sum + el } /  v.size }
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: DataFile can't be coerced into Float
    from (irb):31:in `+'
    from (irb):31:in `block (2 levels) in irb_binding'
    from (irb):31:in `each'
    from (irb):31:in `inject'
    from (irb):31:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):31:in `each'
    from (irb):31:in `each_slice'
    from (irb):31
```

Comment: How are the timebands and the floats within the array?

Comment: as @sawa says: what does the data structure look like. Also: why must it be done with `for` and `while`? there are much more efficient ways of processing collections in Ruby.

Comment: I have just updated my question. As I said above, I'm open to any answer. Thanks in advence.

Comment: It is not helpful to show a formatted table. Show how the inspection of the array looks like.

Comment: where do you get the data from? do you fetch it from a database or is it a plain text file? is performance important for you?

Comment: I'm importing data from a xls file and inserting them to database. All the data is inside a table. I've show you a small picture of the table (so the array) in my answer.

@sawa if you mean array.inspect I've just edited my answer

Comment: @sawa couldn't I provide data you wanted me to give? Sorry if I was too lame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It groups time with minutes 0 to 14 into 15 minute group, timw with minutes 15 to 29 into 30 minute group and so on. For each group, it takes averages.

Here is a working code:

```
require 'date'
a = Hash.new
d = DataFile.all
d.each do |dd|
        a[dd.ras_date.to_s] = [dd.tv1_rtg, dd.tv2_rtg, dd.tv3_rtg, dd.tv4_rtg, dd.tv5_rtg, dd.tv6_rtg, dd.tv7_rtg, dd.tv8_rtg, dd.tv9_rtg, dd.ttv_rtg]
end

number_of_ratings = 10

b = Hash.new
c = Hash.new
a.each do |k,value|
        aa = DateTime.parse(k)
        k_round = (aa + Rational(((aa.min/15+1)*15-aa.min)*60-aa.sec,86400)).to_s
        if b.has_key?(k_round)
        else
                b[k_round] = Array.new(number_of_ratings){|i| 0}
                c[k_round] = 0
        end
        b[k_round] = b[k_round].zip(value).map{|pair| pair.reduce(&:+) }
        c[k_round] = c[k_round]+1
end
b.each do |key,value|
        if c[key]!=0
                n_array = Array.new(number_of_ratings){|i| c[key]}
                b[key] = b[key].zip(n_array).map{|pair| pair.reduce(&:/) }
                p "#{key} => #{b[key]}"
        end
end
```

### **Edit:**

```
k_round = (aa + Rational(((aa.min/15+1)*15-aa.min)*60-aa.sec,86400)).to_s
```

`aa` is a DateTime object.

`Rational` is a function to make a rational number as in Mathematics. Rational(3,4) = 3/4

`to_s` is a function to convert a number(float, int, any number) to string.

In a day, there are 86400 seconds.

This expression `((aa.min/15+1)*15-aa.min)*60-aa.sec` rounds up the minute part to 15 integral multiple and resets the second part to 0.

Simple example of rounding up 34.45 to the multiple of 15 is:

34/15 = 2.26 which rounds up to 3. Now, multiple it by 15, which makes it 45.

Second part of time is 45. So, reset it to zero.

So, we add the time in hour units, so we convert seconds to hours, using `Rational` function.

You can use 5, 30 and 60 minutes like:

```
integral_multiple = 5
k_round = (aa + Rational(((aa.min/integral_multiple+1)*integral_multiple-aa.min)*60-aa.sec,86400)).to_s
```

Comment: Oh My God... I've been really shocked when I see your answer. Thank you very much for your great answer! Your solution is much pretty professional for me to use. Previous answer (above) was depending on position of elements using each_slice. But yours depends on exact DateTime data. I really very very appriciate your help. There are many aspects of your answer which is beyond my ruby skills. So I need to study on this to completely resolve :) I must do it myself because asking for explaination to you would be so rude after this looong answer. Thank you!!

Comment: How can I reuse this code for "5" minutes, "30" minutes or "1 hour"? `k_round = (aa + Rational(((aa.min/15+1)*15-aa.min)*60-aa.sec,86400)).to_s` line is a little bit confusing to me :s

Comment: I think I've understood. Your solution is exact answer of my question. Nevertheless, above answer fits my needs more practically. But because of your targeted answer, I'm accepting your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an array of values you want to `slice` by `15` and find a medians for. Forget about minutes, then:

```
vals.each_slice(15) { |v|
 puts v.inject(0.0) { |sum, el| sum + el } / v.size
}
```

`each_slice` method here is to slice an array on pieces by 15 elemetns. `inject` is iterating through elements and aggregates the value in the `sum`, according to the code block. Code block must return the value to be aggregated. Hope it helps.

In a case you have complicated values in an array (e. g. `Hash`,) you are to `sum` what you really want to sum:

```
vals.each_slice(15) { |v|
  puts v.inject(0.0) { |sum, el| sum + el.tv1_rtg } / v.size
}
```

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for your answer. There are two new things to me with your code. `each_slice` and `inject`. In fact, some explaination about the code block would be appriciated. Could you explain please? I'm not clear with `v.inject` and `|sum, el|` thank you

Comment: Well, because of just making me aware of existance of `each_slice` method, I must accept your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you. In my case, I had to use `to_a` after each_slice(15).

Comment: I'm getting "DataFile can't be coerced into Float" error... Do you have any idea about reason of it?

Comment: @scaryguy Would you please show the full stack? Like _I did that and I got that_. Then we’ll be able to answer.

Comment: I've just updated my question. See edit-3 please. Thanks in advence!

Comment: You got smth from `DataFilea.all` and then try to add it to `sum`. It’s now up to you to extract the data you need (of a type float.)

Comment: Well, I guess that's what I would appricate if you'd help about :)

Comment: I definitely would if I could. To my pity I have no clue what `DataFile` data actually is. Sorry.

Comment: Err, you could find inspection of DataFile at my Edit-2 section.

Well, in fact @Neeraj T's answer is very close to work for me. But I wonder how would your solution result. each_slice(15) works fine to easily get ratings by 15 groups. But Error I got made me confuse.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn’t likely wake up when I had the previous comment written :-) See an update.

Comment: Dear mudasobwa, thank you very much for your great answer! It's definetly what I need and it's very very practical to implement. However, answer below is  the exact answer of the question heading. Because of that I've changed my accepted answer to him BUT I've upvoted you and I'm going to use your solution. Thank you very much and sorry if I gave any inconviences.

Comment: SO is here to provide you with the best answer you _needed_. I’m glad we were helpful ☺